# AppDelegate complaining Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I am trying to read and write a value from the `AppDelegate`. I end up having an exception

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate myViewDelegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc07a9b0'
```

In `APPDelegate.h`

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    MyView *myViewDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyView *myViewDelegate;
```

in `APPDelegate.m`

```
- (void) _application:(UIApplication *)application commonInitializationLaunching:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
...
    self.myViewDelegate = [[MyView alloc] init];

}
```

---

In `MyView.h`
  I have a `NSDate *d;`

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDate *d;
```

and `@synthesis d;` in `MyView.m`

---

In `PaymentView.m`

```
- (void) loadView{
    [super loadView];
     AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     del.myViewDelegate.d = myDate;// myDate is a NSDate
}
```

Comment: Are you using newest Xcode with auto @synthesize for that property ?

Comment: What is `TKAppDelegate`? Is this your actual code? It doesn't all seem to make sense...

Comment: typo. it should be AppDelegate

Comment: What is `auto @synthesize `? I am using xcode 4.6

Comment: Btw why your AppDelegate is extending NSObject instead of UIResponder ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using auto @synthesize from newest Xcode, add this to you AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize myViewDelegate;
```

Also remove that - if you have property + synthesize you don't need that:

```
MyView *myViewDelegate;
```

Comment: So you want me to remove `@synthesize myViewDelegate;` ?

Comment: I didn't see this in your question post - so I suggested to add this and remove MyView *myViewDelegate; declaration

Comment: What about `@property (nonatomic,strong) MyView *myViewDelegate;` ? should i remove it ?

Comment: Nope you need that in your header file - it's public property declaration, than you need @synthesize in your .m file - it will generate setter and getter functions for you.

Comment: What you have in your main.m file ? Is it exactly like that ? int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); ?

Comment: Actually i have added a project within another project. It's the project that i added that is crashing.

Comment: You won't be able to do it this way - there should be only one AppDelegate class in your workspace.

Comment: There's only one AppDelegate. The other i have given a prefix to it so it differentiates.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass a value between 2 classes ? Any other method except for --> `A *a = [[A alloc] init]; a.parameter=@"ddd"`

Comment: Properties or methods. Looks like you should read through basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually AppDelegate's parent class is UIResponder.. so my guess is that when you call this,

```
 AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

the delegate you are getting back is not your class... and when you try to call myViewDelegate on the returned object, it doesn't have that property. Find main.m class in your source code, and see your AppDelegate class is passed in similar to the line below

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

if that AppDelegate class is actually your class and when you cmd + click on the class name, it should take you to that class source.